# No Sharepoint Configuration Wizard

Tags: permissions, configuration-wizard

I've Installed Shaerpoint 2013 Server as standalone and SQL Server 2012 on a single machine using the default Administrator account.
When I went into `Configuration Wizard`, I can't see `Sharepoint Configuration Wizard`.
When I checked in `Site settings`, Administrator has `Full Access`.

I googled the problem, most of them suggest running IE as Admin, but that doesn't work for me.